# How to Get .NET version of Each app running on IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, .net, powershell, iis

Consider more than 2 .net applications running in IIS Server, They may be running on either Targeted .NET framework Version (If It is available in Server Machine) or later .net Version. Is there any way to Get the .NET version of Each app running on the IIS Server in a single shot

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to know?

Comment: What do you mean by "Application Target Version"? That's not a technical term in ASP.NET nor IIS.

Comment: Microsoft Ending Support for .NET Framework 4.5.2, 4.6 and 4.6.1

Comment: What matters is the installed version of .NET Framework on the machine as they're all backwards-compatible. If the server has .NET Framework 4.8 installed then ASP.NET applications that were originally built for .NET 4.5, 4.5.2, 4.7.2, etc will all work fine.

Comment: do we need to do anything or they will automatically run on newer version

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Just update the installed .NET Framework version.